# Having great difficulty centering text (horizontally) on a webpage that contains a background image

Tags: css, html

I have spent many hours searching, testing (using many fine examples) on how to accomplish centering test (horizontally) on a page, but I can't find the root cause of my issue. Either the background image won't show up, but in all cases the text hugs the left side of the page either in the upper left corner (most likely due to the use of .) If the image shows up, the text will show up in the lower left corner below the image (even when using position absolute.) The latest code sample that I tried is the following:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>

  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Arizona Sunset</title>

  <style type="text/css"

.image {
    position:relative;
 }

.text {
left: 0;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
top: 315px;
width: 100%
 }


 </style>

 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="image">
<img src="bg-image5.jpg" width="100%" height="2540"/>
<div class="text">
   Yadda, Yadda, Yadda
</div>
 </div>
  </body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you inserting image or background image? Use `background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg");` in your css if you need a background image. Your text shouldn't then be inside ´<div class="image">`

Comment: @ZZ-bb, I'm attempting to use a background image... I have done as recommended, but still no joy.

Comment: @ZZ-bb, I'm attempting to use a background image... I have done as recommended, but still no joy. I would post the code, but I don't understand the mini markup rules for this site. The background image url in css is relative, since it is in the same folder as the webpage. I pulled the text from the div and put it in a <p tag. all I get is a blank page when viewed in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the somewhat standard way to use background image. Put the image to `body` and text could be inside a `div` (here the `div's` `id` is "content"). Try the code below. Remove the comments and see what happens. (Comment the `background-image` in the `body` when removing the comment from the `content` of course)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
body{
background-image:url('bg-image5.jpg');
//background-repeat: no-repeat; //Image repeats automatically in the whole body of the page.
}

#content {
  //background-image:url('reminder2.jpg'); //If used here, image shows up only where there is text. Use minimum height or something else to include the whole image if necessary.
  text-align:center;
  //min-height:1000px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
  <p>Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Couple of links:

- http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_background_image_codes.cfm
- http://www.echoecho.com/htmlbackgrounds02.htm

The backgroung image in itself should not be important. It adds to the visuality of the site but it's not an important image that should be showed in a whole (it's on the background, it's not an image in an image gallery etc.). The normal repeatibility and functionality of an background image might be an issue, if you'd like to use multiple images in the different `sections` or `div's` on a single page.

Comment: ,@Tikkes, etal, Problem solved! I ended up rebuilding the page from the ground up using code samples from [link](w3schools.com) as well as some of your suggestions. Thank you so much for all of your help and guidance. ~alpineHyker

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="image">
<img ...>
</div>

<div class="text>
text
</div>

body {
width: 100%;
}

.image {
position: relative;
}

.text {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
...
}
```

I usually center by letting the browser do it automatically with `margin` set to `auto`

Comment: Thanks so much for responding Tikkes.

Answer (score 0):

put the

```
  text-align:center;
```

in the .image class

and use css

```
background-image:url('paper.gif');
```

to put the background in the .image div

Comment: ,@Tikkes, Thank you for responding! I have done as recommended, but still no joy. I would post the code, but I don't understand the mini markup rules for this site. The background image url in css is relative, since it is in the same folder as the webpage. I pulled the text from the div and put it in a <p tag. all I get is a blank page when viewed in firefox